# Multiple Condition on one column in sql

Tags: sql

I have an employee table with headers

```
usr_key 
usr_manager_key 
usr_email
usr_first_name 
usr_last_name
```

My condition is 
i want to print the following details for the user

```
usr last name , first name , email , manager email
```

how to put condition , please note that usr_key and usr_manager_key are same attributes , i am having trouble in creating a condition for this manager email field column , please suggest

Answer (score 1):

You need to  join the same table twice with different alias names

```
select emp.usr_first_name, emp.usr_last_name, emp.usr_email, 
       mgr .usr_email as mgr_email
from your_table emp
left join your_table mgr on emp.usr_manager_key = mgr.usr_key
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in order to show you an alternative: You can place a subquery in the select clause:

```
select
  usr_last_name, usr_first_name, usr_email,
  (
    select mgr.usr_email
    from mytable mgr
    where mgr.usr_key = usr.usr_manager_key
  ) as mgr_email
from mytable usr
order by usr_last_name, usr_first_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

### You can use this SQL query

```
SELECT table1.usr_first_name, table1.usr_last_name, table1.usr_email, 
    table2.usr_email 
 FROM table1, table2
    WHERE table1.usr_key = table2.usr_manager_key;
```

Comment: That join syntax should not be used any more. It is outdated for 25 years now.